# Unexpected CSS overflow glitch

Tags: css, mobile, overflow, responsive

I have been struggling an issue I have using CSS overflow.

I have a page that I intend to be responsive. The navigation menu is what is causing my issue.

Specifically the "overflow-x: hidden" declaration...

At first I thought the issue could be related to devtools, (or rather my misuse of it) but I have tested the site on two mobile phones and it's the same there...

The interesting thing is how the overflow is not hidden until there is a click event, I think the solution is related to this fact... maybe haha

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_hsCahD-1Ig

I'd really appreciate anyone taking a look at the video and giving me some advice. Thanks.

UPDATE: As pointed out... I should really add the code too...

HTML (index.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Responsive Sliding Nav</title>
    
</head>    

<body>
    <nav>
        <div class="logo">
            <h4>NAV BAR</h4>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav-links">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="burger">
            <div class="line1"></div>
            <div class="line2"></div>
            <div class="line3"></div>
        </div>
        
    </nav>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS (style.css):

```
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    
}

html {
    background: url(tst.jpg);
    //background-size: auto 100vh;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat
}

nav{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 8vh;
    // background-color: #5D4954;
    background-color: rgba(93, 73, 84, 0.79);
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.logo{
    color: rgb(226, 226, 226);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.nav-links{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    width: 50%;
}

.nav-links li{
    list-style: none;
}

.nav-links a{
    color: rgb(226, 226, 226);
    text-decoration: none;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.burger{
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.burger div{
    width: 25px;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: rgb(226, 226, 226);
    margin: 5px;
    //transition: all 0.3s ease;

}

@media screen and (max-width:1024px){
    .nav-links{
        width: 60%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px){
    body {
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    
    .nav-links{
        position: absolute;
        right: 0px;
        height: 92vh;
        top: 8vh;
        //background-color: #5D4954;
        background-color: rgba(93, 73, 84, 0.7);
        
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        width: 50%;
        transform: translateX(100%);
        transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
    }
    .nav-links li {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    .burger {
        display: block;
    }
}

.nav-active {
    transform: translateX(0%);
}

@keyframes navLinkFade {
    from{
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateX(50px);
    }
    to{
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateX(0px);
    }
}
```

JS (app.js):

```
const navSlide = () => {
    const burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
    const nav = document.querySelector('.nav-links');
    const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-links li');
    
    
    
    
    burger.addEventListener('click', () => {
        //Toggle Nav
        nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');
        
        //Animate Links
        navLinks.forEach((link, index)=>{
            if (link.style.animation) {
                link.style.animation = '';
            } else {
                link.style.animation = `navLinkFade 0.5s ease forwards ${index / 7 + 0.5}s`;
            }
        });
    });

}

navSlide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not provide any information on how you have created everything (HTML/CSS/Javascript), the only thing I can help you with just by looking at the video is that you probably never set the html or body width/height. So add the following lines in your CSS file:

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%
}
```

But next time, please be sure to provide more details and **code**.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. I tried
```
html, body {width:100%; height:100%}
```
It didn't fix things unfortunately.
I've added the code now, though. If you wouldn't mind casting your eye over it I'd be really grateful thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try by adding !important property like this:

```
 @media screen and (max-width:768px){
   body {
     overflow-x: hidden!important;
   }
......
}
```

if this doesn't work you should try adding overflow-x:hidden to html as well. Try with and without !important.
Hope this would fix your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your input Jovan. I have tried using !important... with both variations of applying to the html and body.... no luck yet.

I was wondering if it had anything to do with .nav-links (line 76) being set to absolute positioning, where it's parent .nav (line 16) is set to flex... idk really a shot in the dark.

Comment: Also I find it interesting that when I click on any of the navigation links, the whole layout suddenly snaps into the correct layout as intended (i.e. the extra space where the "hidden" nav was suddenly disappears)

Answer (score 0):

Try to move display properties from .nav-links to .nav-active class and set .nav-links display:none
Something like this

```
.nav-links {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    height: 92vh;
    top: 8vh;
    /* background-color: #5D4954; */
    background-color: rgba(93, 73, 84, 0.7);
    width: 50%;
    transform: translateX(100%);
    transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
    display: none;
}

.nav-active {
   transform: translateX(0%);
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   align-items: center;
}
```

Hope this helps :)
Cheers